# Best word for portfolio / projects / references?

Tags: synonyms

what would be the best word to describe finished projects / websites / applications?

It should be for company web page and it should be clear that after click person will see list of projects / websites / applications done in past.

Comment: What's wrong with *portfolio*?

Comment: Maybe it is good word, I am not sure and that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct word is "portfolio."

"Portfolio" is also used to describe a list of financial investments. If this is a financial company, or you think that the context demands it, then you can append the word "Design" or "Financial" to avoid ambiguity. ("Design Portfolio").

There is no reason for anyone to assume that a portfolio is the complete and unabridged collection of all works created: in fact while it is part of the definition of the word, it is rarely the case in practice.

Answer (score 0):

How about "projects done"?

I think *portfolio* is a page that contains all these projects with a single logo or screenshot.

Comment: "Completed projects" I could understand; but "projects done" is not the first thing a native speaker would produce.